# How to limit text extraction until specific character using regex and python

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I have a sentence:

```
text = "Alun-alun/NNP Jombang/NNP tepatnya/RB Depan/IN SMP/NNP 2/CDP Jombang/NNP Besok/NNP pagi/NN :/: :/: :/: Minggu/NNP"
```

I like to extract any word from tag `/IN` until last word with `/NNP` tag.

The code so far can extract the `Depan/IN SMP/NNP 2/CDP Jombang/NNP Besok/NNP pagi/NN :/: :/: :/: Minggu/NNP`. But I want it to stop if the code meet either `/:` or `/IN` tag. Here is the code so far:

```
import re

def entityExtract(text):
    # text = re.findall(r'([^\s/]*/IN\b[^/]*(?:/(?!IN\b)[^/]*)*/NNP\b)', text)
    text = re.findall(r'([^\s/]*/IN\b[^/]*(?:/(?!IN\b)[^/]*)*/(?:NNP|CDP)\b)', text)
    return text

text = "Alun-alun/NNP Jombang/NNP tepatnya/RB Depan/IN SMP/NNP 2/CDP Jombang/NNP Besok/NNP pagi/NN :/: :/: :/: Minggu/NNP"

extract = entityExtract(text)

print text
print extract
```

Output:

```
['Depan/IN SMP/NNP 2/CDP Jombang/NNP Besok/NNP pagi/NN :/: :/: :/: Minggu/NNP']
```

Expected result is:

```
['Depan/IN SMP/NNP 2/CDP Jombang/NNP Besok/NNP]
```

What is the best way to solve it?

Comment: Your expected result does not match your problem definition. You say that you want to extract any word after tag /IN until any word with /NNP tag. `'Depan/IN'` is _not_ after tag `/IN` and should not be included. `'SMP/NNP'` is a word with `/NNP` tag and should not be included either. The expected results must be an empty string. Please double check.

Comment: @DYZ thanks for the correction, i fixed my question. hope everyone understand my point.

Comment: I've edited the question to alleviate some of the confusion that still existed. If it is ok, please accept edits, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^\s/]*/IN\b([^/]*/(?!IN\b|:\b)[^\s^/]*\b)*[^/]*/NNP\b`

Am as confused as @DYZ about where you want to stop, so I based my regex on your output.
I believe you want to extract `'word/tag'` sections of the string and `word+tag` are strongly coupled.

Where you want to stop your tag at without including it is controlled by this group `(?!IN\b|:\b|NN\b)`

Check regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/ExWczH/1)

Comment: This is based on my best guess but am happy to edit my answer based on refining your question.

Comment: I think I understood your question and edited my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: The forward-slash is not a special character, so there's no need to escape it.

Comment: acknowledged, for some reason the regex site needed it, probably I was choosing a different regex interpreter!

Comment: Yes, that site defaults to php, rather python. (PS: you also seem to have a rogue `^` in the third character range).

Comment: thanks @bulbus, it solve it. note that your solution result give me two items. I combine your solution with my function. the final code is `[^\s/]*/IN\b[^/]*(?:/(?!IN\b|:\b)[^/]*\b)*/(?:NNP|CDP)\b`. Thanks

Comment: @ekhumoro can you check if it is fine? Also can you let me know why the regex site asks me to escape `/`

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the answer from @bulbus and the regex that @ytomo showed in the comments, which is:

```
[^\s/]*/IN\b[^/]*(?:/(?!IN\b|:\b)[^/]*\b)*/(?:NNP|CDP)\b
```

My problem is, this one - and the other proposals - do not follow a logic order to create a regex for the problem at hand. Let me show you:

The first part, before the repeating group `[^\s/]*/IN\b[^/]*` which I'm going to simplify to `\w+/IN\b`[^/]*' matches more than you should want to. Look at [example 1](https://regex101.com/r/YYwLEn/1).

What you're solving here, in words, is:

- read a \w+/IN group
- followed by any number of \s[^/]+/\w+ groups, that's not a \w+/IN\b
- as long as you can read.....until
- ....you've matched the last NNP or CDP group you can find.

Translate that directly to a regex and you'll come up with a more readable version. (JMHO)

1. `\w+/IN\b(\s[^/]+/[^\s]+)` read first group after IN-group ([example 2](https://regex101.com/r/YYwLEn/2/))
2. `\w+/IN\b(\s[^/]+/[^\s]+)*` repeat that second group ([example 3](https://regex101.com/r/YYwLEn/3))
3. `\w+/IN\b(\s[^:/]+/(?!IN|:)[^\s]+)*` ignore :/: and \w+/IN groups ([example 4](https://regex101.com/r/YYwLEn/5))
4. `\w+/IN\b(\s[^:/]+/(?!IN|:)[^\s]+)*\s\w+/(NNP|CDP)\b` Make sure your last group is NNP or CDP ([example 5](https://regex101.com/r/YYwLEn/6))

If we compare this one to the proposed result of @ytomo in the comments of the preceding answer, there seems to be not that much difference. However, the reason I even bothered to answer is, that a regex should readable and according to some logic. Your code is going to be in production tomorrow, and - when your code breaks - someone has to check it under some time pressure.

Comment: `\w+/IN\b(\s\w+/(?!IN|:)\w+\b)*\s\w+/(NNP|CDP)\b` Following your guidelines just made a few edits... https://regex101.com/r/YYwLEn/8

Comment: Took liberty to remove leading : condition as OP did not point to out.

Comment: Looks even simpler. Well done. As a follow-up to your adaptation: apparently ':/NDP' is not a possible string in your example. That should have been pointed out in your question.